# InputField AutoSize Speed Issue

Tags: windows, inputfield

How do I have an `InputField` adjust to fill the remaining size of the window automatically?  For example:

[image]

Using the `ImageSize` option often either freezes or takes 5 seconds or longer to run in Mathematica 8.0 in Windows 7.  **No longer an issue.**

Comment: If characters are fixed-width, find out the width of a character and divide by this?

Comment: @shrx With all the different Unicode variations, or even a common example for mathemaiica users the -> I can't really imagine the `InputField` contain a fixed width font, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the `ImageSize` option for `InputField`?

Comment: @Silvia `ImageSize` just seems to take forever to evaluate in mathematica for me.  I am going to edit the question example that shows the speed issues.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't encounter any speed issue with that option. Could you describe your issues more precisely?

Comment: @Silvia Mathemaitca often seems to borderline freeze and takes longer then 5 seconds for the initial running of the command.  Any subsequent running of the same commands seems to work fine though.

Comment: @Silvia Restarted mathemaitca add there are no longer any issues. :|  Not sure why, if you would like you can post a answer and mark you as having the right answer.  I think there was a cell leek from another notebook, therefore I am no longer able to reproduce the answer.

Comment: I think you can answer the question yourself. :) But I'd say, your comment suggests that the problem asked in OP does not really exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if 124px as the difference will work in all Operating System, but it certainly seems to work in Windows 7 M8.0.

```
width1 = 100;
width = Dynamic[(WindowSize /. 
      Options[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize])[[1]]];
Grid[{{
   InputField["fixed", String,
    ImageSize -> {width1, Automatic}],
   InputField["dynamic", String, 
    ImageSize -> {Dynamic[width] - 124 - width1, Automatic}]
   }}]
```